# Can't run .value() on non-existant property of non-existant object

Tags: javascript, node.js, datastore

i use stormdb
my database structure:

(id == 1)

```
[id]: {
    text: [
      "example", "text"
    ],
    pictures: ["111"],
    chance: {
      "global": 20,
      "demotivator": 10,
      "poll": 10,
      "mem": 10,
      "sticker": 10,
      "bugurt": 10,
      "anekdot": 10
    },
    isGold: false
  }
```

i want to push in "text" string "hello", use this:

```
db.get(`conversations`).get(1).get("text").push("hello").save();
```

but i have error: Error: Can't run .value() on non-existant property of non-existant object.

what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your database is not stored or named the way you think it is.
You might have created it wrong.

Try each of these:

---

```js
console.log( db.get( 'conversations' ).value() );
```

If it fails, your database does not exist.

---

```js
console.log( db.get( 'conversations' ).get( 1 ).value() );
```

If it fails, there is no id '1' entry.

---

```js
console.log( db.get( 'conversations' ).get( 1 ).get( "text" ).value() );
```

If it fails, your 'text' list does not exist.

---

This will tell you what part of your database or entry is missing.